# Spring does not perform validation in REST controller

Tags: java, spring, validation

I try to perform validation using javax annotations where data transfer object for User is being processed (UserDTO) but without expected success.

Here is controller:

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true")
@RequestMapping(value= "/postAccountData", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public @ResponseBody String postAccountData(@Valid UserDTO userData, 
BindingResult result) { 

System.out.println(" Is userData not null?  " + userData != null);

System.out.println("BindingResult : " + result + " has errors: " + 
result.hasErrors());

return "Response from POST account!";

}

}
```

Here is the object (UserDTO) :

```
public class UserDTO {

@NotNull
@NotEmpty 
public String firstName;

@NotNull
public String lastName;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
public String password;
public String matchingPassword;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@NotBlank
public String email;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
public String description;

}
```

When I use Postman to sent (POST) data then it is correctly parsed as an UserDTO object but I am not able to trigger any error thus hasErrors() method returns false at each invocation when null fields are present in retrieved UserDTO object.
What am I missing?

Comment: Add `@Validated` to any class that has the javax validation annotations.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing @RequestBody

```
public @ResponseBody String postAccountData(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userData, 
      BindingResult result) { 

      System.out.println(" Is userData not null?  " + userData != null);

      System.out.println("BindingResult : " + result + " has errors: " + 
      result.hasErrors());

      return "Response from POST account!";
```

Comment: No it does not work with @RequestBody either. Sorry

Comment: @Sinny it looks weird so, if you can share a code repo so that we might help you.

Comment: I will try ASAP to make it public. Maybe I am missing some beans (Processors) that may be necessary?

Comment: @Sinny pehaps you need to add getters and setters on those fields

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @Settter above UserDTO.
Library = lombok

Comment: From which library does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code 'as it is' in a spring boot application. Working fine, even without @RequestBody.  I suggest to check your imports and validation library.